# Find occurence probabilities in finite O-1 regex

Tags: regex, algorithm, probability

I'm searching a fastest algorithm to compute probabilities of occurrence of 0-1 in regex.

I explain ..

For instance I have this regex 0*110+10* where + mean at least one time. more over i know that the size of the sequence will be of 6.
Thus I can produce all possibilities:

```
                                   110001
                                   110010  
                                   110100
                                   011010
                                   011001
                                   001101
```

So with this enumeration i know that the first one have 0.5 probability to be 1, the second 5/6 to be 1. But to compute these probabilities i must enumerate all possibilities. Does exist an algorithm which can give faster the occurence probabilities ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What's an *O-1 regex*?

Comment: I think you'll want to have a look at [Counting words accepted by a regular grammar](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/8200/13671)